# Depending on whether tabs or buffers are being used, map <C-J> to :tabnext OR :bnext intelligently

Tags: vim

I would like to start using buffers from time to time (rather than always using tabs).

I've become accustomed to using a short-cut, Ctrl+J & Ctrl+K to move between tabs.

Is there a way to map these short-cuts in a way that will handle tabs or buffers intelligently?

Comment: You can switch between tabs using :tabn and :tabp, or you can use gt/gT while you're in normal mode

Comment: While that's true, the question is about using one short-cut to call `:tabn` or `:bn`, depending on whether tabs are in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about switching tabs when there are multiple, and switching buffers where there's only one tab page?! That can be done with a simple mapping:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <C-j> :<C-u>if tabpagenr('$') > 1<Bar>tabnext<Bar>else<Bar>bnext<Bar>endif<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an interesting but under-used and semi-impractical option that allows you to switch to a buffer where it is instead of right here: `:help 'switchbuf'`.

It's interesting because the default behavior of `:bn` (for example, it's te same for all `:b*` commands) is to replace the current buffer by the one you are switching to, whether it's already displayed elsewhere or not.

It's under-used because it only works with `:sb`-related and quickfix commands.

It's semi-impractical because, when the buffer you are switching to is not already displayed somewhere, `:sb` opens it in a new split.

There's obviously room for improvement, here.

Anyway, you could try something like this:

```
set switchbuf=useopen,usetab
nnoremap <C-j> :sbnext<CR>
```

or entirely stop using tabs as they are not designed and adapted to work how you want them to work.

Comment: You're right, the opening of a buffer in a split is impractical. Is there a way to open the buffer in a split then immediately shift the previously opened buffer off screen? Sorry to be a pain, and thanks for the knowledge..

Comment: You can use `^W_` and `^W|` to "maximize" a window, but that still shows the statusline (and possibly vertical split bar). It might be feasible to have a function check the buffer list and trigger `:bn` or `:sbn` depending on whether the target buffer is already open.

Comment: Actually, the idea of a "smart" command that does one thing in one situation and another thing in another situation is not very "vimm-y". We tend to have many highly specialized commands instead. Here is another idea: `nnoremap <C-j> :sbnext <bar> only<CR>`. It's really dirty IMO, I guess that you can't avoid writing a function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
:map <C-J> <Esc>:tabnext<CR>
```

This will present a numbered list and required number can be entered to access the required buffer

```
:nnoremap <C-J> :buffers<CR>:buffer<Space>
```